# is this still allowed in grails 2.1.0?

Tags: grails

his is this still allowed in grails 2.1.0 because it does not seem to be saving to the database.

```
            def post = new Post()
            post.message = params.message
            post.author = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
            post.save()
```

Also is there a way I can check to see its its saved?

Thanks

Comment: do you have errors on post object - print them out with: post.errors?.allErrors.each { log.error it }

Comment: Sargamichel, all domain class properties are nullable: false by default. Are you testing your domain class constraints in unit tests? Check your constrains and domain behaviors in unit tests

Comment: You should read GORM Gotchas, an excelent serie wrote by Peter Ledbrook: 1. http://blog.springsource.org/2010/06/23/gorm-gotchas-part-1/ 2. http://blog.springsource.org/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/ 3. http://blog.springsource.org/2010/07/28/gorm-gotchas-part-3/

Answer (score 2):

1. Always check the result of save:

   ```
   if (!post.save(flush: true)) {
       log.error(post.errors)
   }
   ```
2. Use `springSecurityService.currentUser`.

Comment: spring-security-core plugin inject a few convenient properties in your controller. Thus you can use the "principal" property instead from springSecurityService.currentUser. ie: post.author = principal

Comment: Nope, the principal is a `GrailsUser` and just a POGO, not the user/person domain class that GORM requires

Answer (score -1):

That looks valid. Without knowing your constraints and domain it's hard to say more.

You can confirm a `save()` call works by with `failOnError: true`, as in `post.save(failOnError: true)`

Comment: failonerror usage is generally a bad practice if you are in a controller or a service, it could be useful in bootstrap (creating entities) or in tests. better validate and get any errors.

Comment: You're right it is, but the question doesn't mention that, the four line snippet with no context just doesn't work. I think failOnError is a valid way to quickly find out if the save is failing, which is the question.

Comment: As he's reading some values from the params, I think he should be in a controller (or at least in a service), places where I wouldn't use the behaviour you're suggesting. Not saying it's a bad practice at all, of course, but there's a context and I think you're solution doesn't fit - IHMO.